# Google is not authenticating a request from a third party Linux app. Why?

Tags: linux, email, calendar, google

My Evolution version up to just prior to this writing had been 3.36.5. Since I'm using metered internet not all of the applications are updated all of the time. Consequently, I would have the following error, Access blocked: GNOME's Evolution request is invalid

Answer (score 0):

When I plugged the same question into the Bard AI, I eventually was suggested to update the app.
This was the Occam's Razor solution in this case. And it turned out to be correct.
At this point I actually asked the question, is 3.36.5 the latest edition of Linux Evolution? It was not.
Getting to the end was still somewhat convoluted. I followed these steps

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install evolution
```

Of course, Evolution is already installed. So, finally, after Googling how to install Evolution 3.46, I came across a reddit  that implied that it might be a good idea to look into http://flathub.org. This was the answer. Since Zorin is my distro, I was able to install the updated version from the CLI with the following command:

```
flatpak install flathub org.gnome.Evolution
```

Once the new version was installed, it authenticated using my gmail and password.